# Subclipse Lock Automatically

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm currently using subclipse with eclipse to connect my project to SVN.  Due to management decisions we must use the lock-modify-unlock model instead of the standard SVN model.  We are accomplishing this by adding the auto prop need-lock.  Subclipse recognizes this and asks us to lock whenever we edit a file, which works but it rather annoying.  Is there any configuration settings we can use to make it automatically take the lock for the file as long as it is not already locked (at that point it can pop up and bother us)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no setting to bypass the dialog.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know.  Has there been any decision for or against this or has it just not really been considered at all?

Comment: I do not recall what conversations may have taken place.  The feature has existed for 7-8 years.  Not many SVN users use forced locking, those that do tend to only use it for files that do not auto-merge.

Comment: That makes sense.  We'll just have to suck it up and deal then, not too big of a deal.  Thanks for your quick answers!